# jQuery search script based on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, search, html-select

I try to do simple search method based on selected option.

Scenario: I have a search form where I need to put a name. Then need to select where I want to search and hit submit. It should open a new window with URL in following format - URL - based on selected option + string from search input. It works if I will put everything inside form value but I need to set actual value in script not in html value.

My HTML:

```
<form>
<input id="search" type="search" placeholder="placeholder">
 <select name="selection" id="selection">
  <option class="level_2" value="1">website1.com</option>
  <option class="level_2" value="2">website2.com</option>
  <option class="level_2" value="3">website3.com</option>
</select>
<button id="submit" type="submit">vyhledat</button>
</form>

<script>  
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#submit').on('click', function(){
        var searchitem = document.getElementById("search");
        var selecteditem = document.getElementById("selection");
        var selectionitem;
         switch($(selecteditem).val()) {
            case "1": selectionitem = "https://www.wikitree.com/genealogy/";
                 break;
            case "2": selectionitem = "https://www.wikitree.com/genealogy1/";
                 break;
            case "3": selectionitem = "https://www.wikitree.com/genealogy2/";
                 break;
            }
        var url = selectionitem.value + searchitem.value;
        window.open(url,"");
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I use alert of "selectionitem" it returns right value, but value is not transferred to "var url = seletionitem.value".

Thank you for your help

Comment: Just used `selectionitem` instead of `selectionitem.value`

Comment: Also, to open in a new tab you need to: `window.open(url, "_blank")`

Comment: @berkobienb Thank you very much it saves me a lot of time :) It works!

Comment: Also, it's recommended in JavaScript to use camelCase for naming variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `selectionitem` instead of `selectionitem.value`